# How to install lazarus on slackware 64 bit?

Tags: slackware

It seems i am unable to find a way how to install lazarus on 64 bit slackware system.

My goal is to make a 64 bit version of my DLL (.so in linux) which was writen in delphi.
All is fine in 32 bit system. I use Arch Linux to build the 32 bit version, and using 1.0.2 Lazarus. I can use the .so file in 32bit slackware 13.1 with no problem.

Here is what i have tried so far:

Succesfuly installed 64bit version of fpc (v2.4.0).
Downloaded source codes of Lazarus from svn `svn co http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk lazarus`. Compile failed with "expected := found in" at `for Node in Self do` line of `avglvltree.pas`.
Found no solutions on google.

Next: I have found some Lazarus tar file v0.9.30, extracted it `make clean all`.
Failed. Again some kind of error at some line in some file.

Next: I have found this page http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/?source=navbar
Downloaded fpc, fpc source and lazarus 1.0.4 packages by going into "Lazarus Linux x86_64 RPM" link.
Turned out RPM belongs to another linux distrbution so `installpkg` doesnt work. Google told me i could use another package manager which was already in slackware, so i did, but then it started spitting out all the `dependency missing` stuff and i was way too tired to search for explanations as to what it was and where can i get it from. Each package resulted in even more errors.

Could somebody please tell me, step by step, how can i install lazarus and compile my dll?

I am sure i am doing something wrong (im really new to linux systems), but i have no idea what and none of the guides out there seem to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appeared to be very simple.

The .rpm files are taken from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20x86_64%20RPM/Lazarus%201.0.4/) .

Instead of using `rpm -Uvh <rpm file>`, need to use `rpm2tgz <rpm file>` command.
  Doing this for all 3 packages will convert .rpm to .tgz.

Next just use `installpkg <tgz file>` command to install them all, one by one. It takes quite a while.

Executing `fpc -i` command will show supported target systems (along with other information) where 'Linux for x86-64' was what was needed.

I had xfce 4 desktop manager installed with my Slackware 13.1 x64 so i ran it using `startxfce4`. Lazarus appeared at the 'Development' menu.

After opening Lazarus and the library project, need to go to  **Project > Project options... > Compiler options > Code generation**. In the **Target platform** section need to change **Target OS** to **Linux** and **Target CPU family** to **x86_64**. Additionaly in **Compiler Options > Other**, had to add **-fPIC** to custom options field.

Saved and built. The generated .so file is now usable under 64 bit SlackWare.

Comment: Lazarus is also found on Slackbuilds.org, and can be managed with sbopkg for better handling of upgrades.  This method does, of course, do the job.